# How to sync two jQuery cycle image sliders?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-cycle

In my single HTML page I am using two image sliders. For both the sliders I have given the same delay time.

When the page is loaded both image slides are syncing but when the image slides run for few minutes they are not syncing correctly.

Is it possible to make them sync?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#slide').cycle({     
        fx: 'fade',
        delay:   -6000,
    });

    $('#content_slide').cycle({     
        fx: 'fade',
        delay:   -6000,
    });
});
```

Comment: This should work fine, can you create a jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: @Amir http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/non-image.php You can see this sliders. After 4 or 5  mins they will not be synced.

Comment: Have you tried giving the outers a class instead of an ID? Then one set of instructions should run both $('.slide').cycle({ ... });

Comment: @DarrenSweeney I tried out all the possibilities but not syncing for long time. Thanks you for you great efforts.